# Difficulty in filtering a list of objects using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have one list List, need to write a common stream based code to filter out the objects in the below two scenarios.

1. Input parameter is dp with value "MAR 2019". If there any matching row found and end date is not null return the row.

   Input:

   ```
   [PT(pn=1, endDate=2019-01-11, dp=MAR 2019),           
   PT(pn=4, endDate=null, dp=APR 2019),        
   PT(pn=6, endDate=2019-05-11, dp=MAY 2019)]
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   PT(pn=1, endDate=2019-01-11, dp=MAR 2019)}
   ```
2. Parameter to the function is "MAR 2019". If there any matching row found and end date is null, need to return all the records until we get a non-null end date

   Input:

   ```
   [PT(pn=1, endDate=null, dp=MAR 2019),      
   PT(pn=4, endDate=2019-04-11, dp=APR 2019),       
   PT(pn=6, endDate=2019-05-11, dp=MAY 2019)]
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   [PT(pn=1, endDate=null, dp=MAR 2019),      
   PT(pn=4, endDate=2019-04-11, dp=APR 2019)]
   ```

```
class PT{       
   Integer pn;      
   Date endDate;      
   String dp;       
}
```

```
List<PT> filteredList11 = availablePT.get()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(PT::getPn))
    .filter(e->)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am bit confused how to write one filter function for the above mentioned scenarios, as we never capture any previous state values while using streams, Kindly advice.

Comment: Could you transform your pseudo code into real java code and post it in your question? What implementation of `List` do you use? How do you add the values to the `List`s?

Comment: @deHar, Thanks, the List is getting populated from a json we receive from third party source.

Comment: OK, that explains where the data is coming from, but how does the java code you currently have look? We can only provide solutions if we exactly know the data types in java. What objects are in the `List`s?

Comment: @dehar, sorry for missing out on the data structure. I have updated the class details, kindly check.

Comment: Can you explain your second requirement a little more detailed? What if there are `null` end dates spread all over the list? Then no real *until* will be possible, but instead something like getting all `PT`s that have an end date which is `null`.

Comment: @deHar, Thanks for your advice, if we have records with all null end dates, we can return an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a method that does what you want to do in the **first part of your question(s)**. This basically streams and filters the given `List<PT>` using only one `.filter` statement:

```
public class StackoverflowMain {

    static class PT {
        Integer pn;
        // Here, I changed your code. You should really use the up-to-date time API
        LocalDate endDate;
        String dp;

        public PT(int pn, LocalDate endDate, String dp) {
            this.pn = pn;
            this.endDate = endDate;
            this.dp = dp;
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Gets a list of all PTs that match the given criterium for the dp class
     * attribute of class PT.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param source the original list that needs to be filtered
     * @param dp     the dp value to be matched
     * @return a list of all PTs that passed the filter criterium
     */
    public static List<PT> getPTWithValidEndDateAndDp(List<PT> source, String dp) {
        return source.stream()
                    .filter(pt -> pt.endDate != null && pt.dp.equals(dp))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // mock the list of PTs that you receive from somewhere
        List<PT> receivedPTs = new ArrayList<PT>();
        // one PT with endDate == null but matching dp
        receivedPTs.add(new PT(1, null, "MAR 2019"));
        // one PT with valid endDate and valid dp, but no matching dp
        receivedPTs.add(
            new PT(4, LocalDate.parse("2019-04-11", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE), "APR 2019")
        );
        // another totally valid PT whose dp does not match
        receivedPTs.add(
            new PT(6, LocalDate.parse("2019-05-11", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE), "MAY 2019")
        );
        // a totally valid PT with the matching dp ---> should be contained in the output
        receivedPTs.add(
            new PT(1, LocalDate.parse("2019-03-11", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE), "MAR 2019")
        );

        // create a list from the valid and matching PTs passing the source list and the
        // dp to be matched
        List<PT> marchPTs = getPTWithValidEndDateAndDp(receivedPTs, "MAR 2019");

        // output the result
        marchPTs.forEach(mpt -> System.out.println("[pn: " + mpt.pn + ", endDate: "
                + mpt.endDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE) + ", dp: " + mpt.dp + "]"));
    }
}
```

> Please note that I changed a part of your code, I replaced the old-fashioned and error-prone use of `java.util.Date` into using `java.time.LocalDate`, which should be preferred nowadays.

I don't know if I will have time enough to provide an example for your second requirement, but I will try…

Answer (score 0):

Part 1:

```
public static List<PT> filterOne(List<PT> input, String dp) 
{
    return input.stream()
             .filter(pt -> pt.endDate != null && pt.dp.equals(dp))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Part 2:

```
public static List<PT> filterTwo(List<PT> input, String dp) 
{
    AtomicBoolean dpFilter = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    return input.stream()
            .filter(obj -> {
                if (dpFilter.get()){
                    if (obj.endDate == null || obj.dp.equals(dp)) {
                        dpFilter.set(false);
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                if (obj.endDate == null && obj.dp.equals(dp)){
                    dpFilter.set(true);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```